# Select more tables after FROM statement?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

this is part of a *security audition*, so there is no way to "change" the query.

Basically, what I found is a flaw that allows statement manipulation, so basically it goes like:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`whatever` = $variable";
```

This is PHP, so as far as I know there is no way to execute multiple queries. Using this SQL Injection, I was able to "clear" this table by running "0 OR 1=1#".

This works just fine, but it doesn't allow me to choose more tables to delete from.

This is, in pseudocode what I want to do:

```
DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`whatever` = **0 OR 1=1, FROM `othertable` WHERE `othertable`.`othercolumn` = 0 OR 1=1**
```

Is this plausible anyhow?

If this isn't reliable, is there any other way I could use this?

Comment: Are you asking how to SQL-inject or how to prevent it?

Comment: How to build the SQL-Injection query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple FROM clauses for the same DELETE statement, so you can't go about it exactly how you'd want to. If the MySQL db had 'allow multiple queries per statement' turned on, you could try to terminate the one DELETE query and then tack on another to the end, so that it'd look like this:

```
DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`whatever` = **0 OR 1=1; DELETE FROM `othertable` WHERE `othertable`.`othercolumn` = 0 OR 1=1**
```

But that's about it.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. So there is no way this can be done? I might post a MySQL bug. xD

Comment: @Jose:  It's not a MySQL issue.  The PHP driver module simply doesn't support it.

Comment: You can in fact delete from multiple tables in one query, but they must be specified in the FROM clause (after there WHERE is too late). PHP is *configured* not to allow multiple queries in one call, other languages might be more permissive.

Comment: @Jose:  Other modules, such as MySQLi, do have support for this.  See MySQLi's `multi_query()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: @zombat Yes, but you can actually enable it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-set-server-option.html

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I don't fully understand the question, but what I take away is that you're building a SQL command as a string and running that string directly against a MySQL database.

You can separate multiple commands using the command separator (usually ';'), so you could run pretty much any command you want as [this comic](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_isk1o8_XWYA/R0ML6q6-HYI/AAAAAAAAAtY/_bm0dffd6Gc/s1600-h/exploits_of_a_mom.png) aptly illustrates.

If your database configuration supports multiple commands (or might in the future if someone changes today's setting), you want to ensure you don't have a command separator as part of the input. See [this article](http://www.askbee.net/articles/php/SQL_Injection/sql_injection.html) for advice on sanitizing your input to prevent this type of attack.

Comment: LOL, that's funny xD. But back to our business, the semicolon doesn't work within the MySQL API (which PHP uses), so there is no way to run "more than one" command.

Comment: Yes, this answer is technically incorrect.  The standard MySQL driver module for PHP does not support multiple statements in a query, so it doesn't matter what your database settings are or what you separate your statements with.  Other modules have support for this however, such as MySQLi's multi_query().

Comment: Well, actually it SUPPORTS it if it is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, multiple queries are not supported by the normal MySQL driver module.  From [the manual for mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query
>   (multiple queries are not supported)
>   to the currently active database on
>   the server that's associated with the
>   specified link_identifier .

Unfortunately for your injection efforts, `DELETE` syntax only supports multiple table deletes by specifying them in the `FROM` clause.  Your injected variable is part of the `WHERE`, so the most damage you can do is to the single specified table.

Contrary to popular belief, you can actually run multiple MySQL statements from PHP, you just have to be using a different database driver module such as MySQLi.  See [MySQLi::multi_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: Yeah, thanks, although it's not really damaging, it's a part of a security audition, as I mentioned :P